# Problem with Ansible Asynchronous actions

Tags: ansible, automation

I'm trying to run two simple tasks

`Task A` starts an Ipref3 server and waits for a client to connect
`Task B` starts to run from *host-1* until the given timeout

once `Task B (host-1)` is over another `Task B` run from host-2

`Task B` starts to run from *host-2* until the given timeout

What is a good approach to orchestrating this use-case?

**This is what I tried**

`Task B` runs the client from multiple hosts (host-1, host-2, ..)

```
- name: Run iperf3 client
  win_command: iperf3 -c {{ iperf_server }} -t {{ iperf_time }} 
  args:
    chdir: "{{ iperf_dest }}"
  register: iperf3_out

- debug:
    var: iperf3_out.stdout
```

`Task A` run the server

```
- name: Start iperf3 server
  shell: iperf3 --server
  async: "{{ iperf_async }}" # iperf_async = iperf_time + 10
  poll: "{{ iperf_poll }}"   # iperf_poll  = 0
```

Is there a way to know when to confirm `Task A` is finished before I move to the next task.

NOTE: Order of execution is important Server (`Task A`) needs to run before the client (`Task B`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Order of execution is important Server (Task A) needs to run before the client (Task B)

Then why are your running Task A async in that case ? Is it just because `iperf --server` is not falling in the background and dying as soon as the shell task finishes ? A quick look at the [documentation](https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php#3doc) shows we can probably work around that problem with something like:

```bash
iperf3 --server --daemon --pidfile /path/to/iperf3.pid --logfile /path/to/log
```

Notes:

- I added the `logfile` option since I guess it can be useful but it is not mandatory for the current issue
- I took for granted you are running the server on a linux platform. Running it on Windows would apparently slightly change the below scenario. See [Running as a service on windows](https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php#service)

From what I understand the last unsolved issue is running the client tasks sequentially on each client host. This can be done using the [`serial` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#rolling-update-batch-size) on your play.

Here is an untested pseudo ansible setup summarizing what I understand from your requirements. Adapt to your real use-case.

**`inventory/iperf_hosts.yml`**

```yaml
---
iperf_servers:
  vars:
    iperf_pid_file: /tmp/iperf.pid
    iperf_log_file: /tmp/iperf.log
  hosts:
    server1.local:
iperf_clients:
  vars:
    iperf_time: 1
    iperf_dest: some\win\directory
  hosts:
    host1.local:
    host2.local:
    host3.local:
```

**`playbook.yml`**

```yaml
---
- name: Start the iperf server
  hosts: iperf_servers
  
  tasks:
    - name: Fire the start command
      command: "iperf3 --server --daemon --pidfile {{ iperf_pid_file }} --logfile {{ iperf_log_file }}"

- name: Launch clients one after the other.
  hosts: iperf_clients
  serial: 1
  
  tasks:
    - name: Run iperf3 client
      win_command: "iperf3 -c {{ hostvars[group['iperf_servers'][0]].inventory_hostname }} -t {{ iperf_time }}"
      args:
        chdir: "{{ iperf_dest }}"
      register: iperf3_out

    - debug:
        var: iperf3_out.stdout

- name: Now we are over with clients, kill the server
  hosts: iperf_servers
  # We already gathered facts at first play so we disable here
  # You might want to disable in all other plays if you don't need facts at all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Slurp pid from file
      slurp:
        path: "{{ iperf_pid_file }}"
      register: slurped_pid

    - name: kill the iperf3 process
      command: "kill {{ slurped_pid.content | b64decode }}"
```